# changing face sizes within facebook like box

Tags: facebook-like

I'm trying to customize the facebook like box, and I need to alter the image size slightly. I've been reading around and it seems to be difficult. Does anyone know a way?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the css by adding your own style for

```
.connect_widget .connect_widget_image{
  width: ##px !important;
  height: ##px !important;
}
```

and also

```
.connect_widget .connect_widget_sample_connection{
  width: ##px !important;
}
```

Did not try but that how I would do it.

Although I think it's not very recommended to change CSS of like button...